# Eclipse throwing Exception on code completition

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

My eclipse shows the following error message if I press "CTRL + SPACE"

```
The 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.TemplateProposalComputer' proposal computer from the 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui' plug-in did not complete normally. The extension has thrown a runtime exception.
```

In the eclipse log I see the following Exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/martin/Programme/eclipse/x64/edition_2021-03/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/2969/0/.cp/icons/full/obj16/staged2465766773545443944.tmp" "write")
at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:897)
at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322)
at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:752)
at ro.sync.security.manager.SandboxSecurityManager.checkWrite(SandboxSecurityManager.java:188)
at java.base/java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2082)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.BundleInfo$Generation.storeContent(BundleInfo.java:384)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.CloseableBundleFile.getFile(CloseableBundleFile.java:223)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry.getFileURL(ZipBundleEntry.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.BundleURLConnection.getFileURL(BundleURLConnection.java:139)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.BundleURLConverter.toFileURL(BundleURLConverter.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor$URLImageFileNameProvider.getImagePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.DPIUtil.validateAndGetImagePathAtZoom(DPIUtil.java:419)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:624)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createResource(ImageDescriptor.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceManager.allocate(DeviceResourceManager.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:88)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ResourceManager.createImageWithDefault(ResourceManager.java:195)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry.get(ImageRegistry.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPluginImages.get(JavaPluginImages.java:643)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.template.contentassist.TemplateEngine.getImage(TemplateEngine.java:196)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.template.contentassist.TemplateEngine.complete(TemplateEngine.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractTemplateCompletionProposalComputer.computeCompletionProposals(AbstractTemplateCompletionProposalComputer.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalComputerDescriptor.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalCategory.computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalCategory.java:340)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.collectProposals(ContentAssistProcessor.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ContentAssistProcessor.computeCompletionProposals(ContentAssistProcessor.java:289)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.AsyncCompletionProposalPopup.lambda$10(AsyncCompletionProposalPopup.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.AsyncCompletionProposalPopup.lambda$9(AsyncCompletionProposalPopup.java:351)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

The mentioned directory `/home/martin/Programme/eclipse/x64/edition_2021-03/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/2969/0/.cp/icons/full/obj16/` exists and is writeable for my user. The outlined file do not exists. So what is the problem here?

I'm currently using eclipse 2021-09 RC1 but I remember I had this issue with the previous eclipse version too. If I disable "Template Proposals" in the content assist this message goes away. But this error can't be normal as this happens again if I reset the content assist to the default values. At least with the defaults Eclipse should always work as expected.

Comment: As a test/workaround, try disabling `SWT template proposal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download page for `eclipse 2021-09 RC1` clearly states

> Please note that this is a developer build which might contain issues.

It might well be a bug on the development version. `RC` means Release Candidate.

Suggestions:

- Use an stable release to reproduce the issue
- [Contribute a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi) for that version.
- As a test/workaround, try disabling `SWT template proposal`

@howlger suggestion on reporting bugs:

> Better report bugs that can be reproduced with a fresh installation of the latest releases candidate, milestone or even better the latest daily integration build than of the latest release.

Comment: You're right. I should not use a RC for production. I'll file a bug report. I had this issue on previous versions of eclipse too and I had this issue quite often tbh. Even on non RC versions. However - I every time only disabled mentioned proposals..

Comment: @MartinFernau Better report bugs that can be reproduced with a fresh installation of the latest releases candidate, milestone or even better the latest daily integration build than of the latest release. (By the way, I cannot reproduce this issue in any of these versions. Are you sure you didn't install it or run Eclipse one time as admin,  what you're not supposed to do?).

Comment: @LMC Please report issues based on the latest build instead of the latest release, best with a patch.

Comment: @howlger I'm totally sure that I didn't run Eclipse as a different user. This issue also comes and go. Now it isn't there even if I restore defaults. I bet in a few days (when I'm pressed for time, of course) this issue will be back and makes me crazy ;) for me this is a mystery...

Comment: @MartinFernau Sure, but more details are needed. Show the log starting with `!SESSION`. Is your Eclipse up to date? Which plugins do you have installed in which IDE package? Which operating system of which version do you have? Where is the Eclipse installation and your workspace located (both, should not on a NFS server)?